# Completely disable the menu when I right click on the desktop (LXDE, Openbox, Ubuntu)

Tags: desktop, openbox, lxde

I would like to setup an old PC as a thinclient for our VMware View infrastructure. I need to disable the menu that pops up when I right-click on the desktop, along with some other things such as disabling the screen saver.

This is what I have done so far:

- Disable LXDE screensaver

  Delete `@xscreensaver –no-splash` from `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart`
- Remove right click desktop menu options

  Right click on desktop and choose `Desktop Preferences`

  Select the advanced tab and check off `Show menus provided by window managers when desktop is clicked`

  Edit `/etc/xdg/openbox/menu.xml` and remove everything between `<menu id=”root-menu” label=”Openbox 3”>` and `</menu>`
- Disable the LXPanel

  Edit `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart` and comment out `@lxpanel –profile LXDE`.

All of this seems to work fine, but when I right-click the desktop I still see this:

[image: Screenshot of the pop-up menu]

How do I kill this?

Comment: It seems you have re-enabled pcmanfm desktop menu. Try to re-execute first part of step two.

Comment: Assuming you mean disable, "check off `Show menus provided by window managers when desktop is clicked`" is precisely what _causes_ this right-click menu provided by PCManFM to be invoked. Setting that checkbox on hides this menu (leaving everything up to the WM a.k.a. OB) but retains its ability to provide background & icons. Disabling PCManFM altogether in autostart would remove all three facilities.

Answer (score 3):

This question is very old, but you need to remove the line from `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart` that is starting pcmanfm. The right-click menu you see there is not from openbox, but from the pcmanfm desktop window.

Answer (score 2):

See [this post](http://forum.slitaz.org/topic/disable-openbox-menu). You have to modify `/etc/xdg/openbox/rc.xml` and "smartly" remove all the tags matching a "ShowMenu" command. This will completely disable the OpenBox menus (all of them), but you can adapt it to your needs, as the file contents are pretty intuitive.

You can also modify a copy of this file under `~/.config/openbox/rc.xml` to make the changes only for a given (set of) user(s), but being familiar with the thin client world, I think you want to remove it completely.

Comment: This never worked for me. Can you please update the right way tested in Ubuntu 13.10 64-bit but does not work.

Comment: This answer is irrelevant. The pictured menu is provided by PCManFM, which owns the root window used to display the desktop (background & icons). OpenBox has no control whatsoever over that menu. Your answer might mislead readers into spuriously deleting other menus they want to keep. [...inhales...] Setting PCManFM to "Show menus provided by window managers" hides its own right-click menu (& replaces it with OB's if thus configured) but retains its ability to provide background & icons. Disabling PCManFM altogether in `autostart` would remove all three facilities.