# Disable Right Click on file (Openbox, LXDE, Pcmanfm)

Tags: openbox, lxde, pcmanfm

I want to disable the right click on a file. It's possible?

I'm actually using Openbox, LXDE and PcManFM.

I had disable the right click to open the menu on the desktop but I want to disable the right click on a file too.

Answer (score 1):

- In the PCManFM preferences toggle the Show Window Manager Menu option (you might have to click advanced).
- Remove the line from `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart` that is starting pcmanfm.
- Change `openbox-lxde` in `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/config` to `openbox`.

See [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36400/completely-disable-the-menu-when-i-right-click-on-the-desktop-lxde-openbox-ub) and [link](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=52000) for more options.

Comment: I don't have a file named `openbox-lxde`.

Comment: It should be an entry in file `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/config`

Comment: In my file `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE` I don't have a file named `config`. I need to create him?

Comment: No, I guess your config is stored in different place. Don't previous steps help? This last step changes to default openbox menu so you can edit it's config manually, may be you don't need this at all.

Comment: My `menu.xml` is in `/home/rpitc/.config/openbox`. But I had read all the file and I just can change the menu when I do a right click on the desktop. I want to disable the right click on a file. When you can choose "cut, copy, etc...".

Comment: First option in my answer didn't help?

Comment: No unfortunately, my right click is still here.

Comment: You can completely disable options to copy/paste files to desktop by removing lines `desktop_manager/command=filemanager` and `file_manager/command=pcmanfm` from `/etc/xdg/lxsession/Lubuntu/desktop.conf`

Comment: This can also be achieved by setting desktop properties [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/AVuztdz.png)

Comment: I doesn't have this line in my `desktop.conf`.

Comment: And how about changing desktop settings as on screenshot?

Comment: It's the same...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20828/discussion-between-kirill-a-and-aragmond).

Answer (score -1):

Remove

```
<mousebind button="Right" action="Press">
<action name="ShowMenu"><menu>root-menu</menu></action>
</mousebind>
```

from `/etc/xdg/openbox/rc.xml`, then reboot.